# Jssor Slider: Plays only Once on Auto

Tags: jssor

For some reason the auto play sider runs through the slides and then stops. If I press the arrow it will run through them at the right speed and loop.

PLEASE HELP!
http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1500, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            $SlideWidth: 687,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            $SlideHeight: 324,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                   //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },
            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 0,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 600));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where can I download?

Comment: I downloaded from here: http://www.jssor.com/download.html

Comment: But it still doesn't work

Comment: I just visited your site, no such problem found. Please describe your problem more in detail. Thanks.

Comment: On this page: http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/ The slider doesn't automattically start. If you press the arrow it will then loop but until you press the arrow it stays on the last slide. It's almost like it goes through the slides before the pages loads and then stops. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Please always specify size in pixel.

You will get it by replacing

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="left: 0px; top: 5px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
```

with

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="left: 0px; top: 5px; width: 687px; height: 324px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked in getting it to auto play but now the size isn't right :(

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the size issue?

Comment: Yes. What's is the exact size issue?

Comment: Thanks! It is scaling down now for some reason. Before it said 100% and it fit in the wooden box but not that I put the exact size it seems to be scaling down. I tried a bigger size to see if it would adject and it wouldn't. You can see here:http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/

Comment: Please replace jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 600)); with jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(parentWidth);

Comment: Thanks you sooooo much! You have been so helpful and I really appreciate it.